# Using a Specific Seed for a Random Number Generator in Java

Tags: java, random, seed, random-seed

I know there's been a lot of questions on Seeds here before already, I've looked through quite a few but am still struggling, sorry if this seems repetitive! Basically I'm prompting the user for an input value (which will be the seed) and then using that seed to generate random values. My code is in two separate files, but I'll try to keep this organized for you.

File 1:

```
Random generator = new Random();

public RandomWalk(int gridSize){

    gridSize = generator.nextInt();
    this.gridSize = gridSize;
}



public RandomWalk(int gridSize, long seed){
    generator.nextInt();
    this.gridSize = gridSize;
}
```

File 2:

```
public static long seed = 0;
int i = 1;
    System.out.println("Enter random seed (0 for no seed): ");
    while (i == 1) {
        seed = scan.nextInt();
        if (!(seed == 0)) {
            if (seed > 0) {
                i++;
                //Generate numbers based on seed entered
            } else {
                System.out.println("You need to enter a positive integer.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Seed is 0, a random seed will be generated");
            //Make this generate a random seed
            i++;
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    getInput();

    RandomWalk walk;
    if (seed==0){
        walk = new RandomWalk(gridSize);
    } else {
        walk = new RandomWalk(gridSize, seed);
    }

    walk.createWalk();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really ask a question, but I'll try to infer it.  Is it that your code is not working as you expected?

One issue I see is that your RandomWalk constructor which takes in a seed never does anything with the seed.  Try this:

```
Random generator;

public RandomWalk(int gridSize){
    generator = new Random();
    gridSize = generator.nextInt();
    this.gridSize = gridSize;
}



public RandomWalk(int gridSize, long seed){
    generator = new Random(seed);
    gridSize = generator.nextInt();
    this.gridSize = gridSize;
}
```

Note that the seed is passed to the Random constructor.  Additionally, your call to generator.nextInt() is made in the 2nd constructor without assigning its return value to gridSize.  I think that may not have been what you intended to do.

You may want to take a look at the [Java SDK documentation for Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).  It has 2 constructors, one which accept a seed parameter and another which essentially makes one up for you.

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I had missed that. Sorry for not explaining it very well the first time. The only problem is that for some reason when I use the same seed as my professor I get slightly different output, ever heard of that before? I'm assuming it's another error somewhere... :/

Comment: Happens to the best of us...  As for the different sequence, I'm not sure...  Is this program running multiple threads, by chance?  That can cause some issues with the repeatability of random number sequences.

Comment: Nope. :s My output ends up being (the first line below) while my professors output ends up being (the second line below)-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1,0] [2,0] [3,0] [3,1] [4,1] [5,1] [5,2] [5,3] [5,4] [5,5]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1,0] [2,0] [3,0] [4,0] [5,0] [5,1] [5,2] [5,3] [5,4] [5,5]

So I'm at a total loss as to why the beginning and end would match up and the middle wouldn't. Gah, pulling my hair out right now.

Comment: I think I'd have to see more code to help you figure this out.  I suspect you're correct that there's another error somewhere and that it's not a problem with the Random class.  Can you share your entire project with us?